# How can I solve mysqli_fetch_assoc error?

Tags: php, css, mysqli

I'm working on a friend list for my website where users can follow, block, unfollow and unblock other users.  My friends table has 3 columns.  A column, for the lower userid, a column for the other user, and a status column that will showcase their relationship.

```
user1 | user2 | status
----------------------
1       2       1
1       3       2
2       3       3
```

I have created a test page to display the login users relationships and separate them into groups by their status. The following code is supposed to display all users who are selected and have status = 1.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
                $friendsql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1 = ? OR user2 = ?";
                $friendstmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($friendstmt, $friendsql)) {
                    echo "error";
                }
                else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($friendstmt, "ii", $userID, $userID);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($friendstmt);
                    $friendresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($friendstmt);
                    echo "<div class='friendStatus1'>";
                        echo "Following";
                        while (($friendrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friendresult)) && ($friendrow['status'] == 1)) {
                            if ($userID == $friendrow['user1']) {
                                $otheruserID = $friendrow['user2'];
                            }
                            else {
                                $otheruserID = $friendrow['user1'];
                            }
                            $otheruserNamesql = "SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userid = ?";
                            $otheruserNamestmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($otheruserNamestmt, $otheruserNamesql)) {
                                echo "error";
                            }
                            else {
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($otheruserNamestmt, "s", $otheruserID);
                                mysqli_stmt_execute($otheruserNamestmt);
                                $otheruserNameresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($otheruserNamestmt);
                                while ($otheruserNamerow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($otheruserNameresult)) {
                                    echo "<div class='friendBox'>";
                                        echo $otheruserNamerow['userName'];
                                    echo "</div>";
                                }
                            }
                         } 
                    echo "</div>";
```

Currently there are two relationships inside of my friends table that have status = 1 with the login user, but my code will only display the first relationship. My while loop has an error that only lets the first relationship spit out.  Can someone help me fix my error?

My CSS

```
.friendListContainer {
        position: relative;
        margin: 60px 0px 37px 0px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 97px);
        max-height: 100%;
        background-color: #777;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .friendBox {
        width: 70%;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #555;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
    .friendStatus1 {
        width: 10%;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 97px);
        max-height: 100%;
        background-color: #666; 
        display: inline-block;
        border-left: 1px solid #444;
        border-right: 1px solid #444;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Comment: Your outer `while` loop has `&& ($friendrow['status'] == 1)` as part of the condition - if you only want these rows add it to your SQL - `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user1 = ? OR user2 = ?) and status = 1`.

Comment: Thank you Nigel that is a better way to do it.  If answer officially I will mark it as correct.

Comment: You should reconcider about the actual database-structure before you move on. Users should not be a column in a table. There should be a table with users that you then relate to. Why? 1. Not flexible. If you want to add more users ..... 2. A relationsship is a a relationship db :-) 3. The code would be easier to maintain and faster. Read on how to create database and relations and joins etc.

Comment: i have another users table, where users are rows instead of columns, this is a separate table strictly for relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer while loop is

```
while (($friendrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friendresult)) && ($friendrow['status'] == 1)) {
```

so if it encounters a row where `$friendrow['status'] == 0`, it will then stop the loop and ignore the rest of the rows (as they are not sorted).

It would be better as part of the condition in the SQL - if you only want these rows add it to your SQL...

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user1 = ? OR user2 = ?) and status = 1
```

(Note the brackets to ensure the correct grouping of the operators).